# Getting Out of memory error in ADF when copying from On-premise to Blob in parquet file format

Tags: azure, jvm, azure-blob-storage, parquet, azure-data-factory

I have around 10M records in an On-premise SQL that I am trying to transfer using my Integration Runtime to my Azure Blob Storage in parquet file format. For 2M records it is transferring with no issue, but when I try to transfer above 2M records I'm getting the following error. I did some research, and I read on a post that it might help changing the environment variable value for java

```
**_JAVA_OPTIONS with value -Xms256m -Xmx16g.**
```

or

```
**_JAVA_OPTIONS with value -Xms256m -Xmx32g.**
```

I tried both and I'm still getting the same error

```
"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorJavaInvocationException,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error occurred when invoking java, message: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space\ntotal entry:11\r\njava.util.ArrayDeque.doubleCapacity(Unknown Source)\r\njava.util.ArrayDeque.addFirst(Unknown Source)\r\njava.util.ArrayDeque.push(Unknown Source)\r\norg.apache.parquet.io.ValidatingRecordConsumer.endField(ValidatingRecordConsumer.java:108)\r\norg.apache.parquet.example.data.GroupWriter.writeGroup(GroupWriter.java:58)\r\norg.apache.parquet.example.data.GroupWriter.write(GroupWriter.java:37)\r\norg.apache.parquet.hadoop.example.GroupWriteSupport.write(GroupWriteSupport.java:87)\r\norg.apache.parquet.hadoop.example.GroupWriteSupport.write(GroupWriteSupport.java:37)\r\norg.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:123)\r\norg.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.write(ParquetWriter.java:292)\r\ncom.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetBatchWriter.addRows(ParquetBatchWriter.java:60)\r\n,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.JniExt.JavaBridgeException,Message=,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.HiveOrcBridge,'",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Copy Data1"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

How about doing a "staging" upload first, as a compressed csv, then taking that compressed csv and move it to destiny but taking blob storage as source. This way you will discard the issue being the self hosted IR. This workaround has worked for me up to 5M rows, so you might as well give it a try.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I removed old IR created new one now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error slightly different error message  "Unable to retrieve Java exception" (no heap size ), but mine was resolved by changing the compression type to **'none'**. by default the snappy compression on the parquet sink file was causing the issue